# How can I add an email alias to a domain alias in Google Apps?

Tags: email, google-apps

I have the Google apps account: `domain1.com`

I have the following accounts set up:

- Bill (bill@domain1.com)
- Ben (ben@domain1.com)
- Joe (joe@domain1.com)

I have the domains `domain2.com` set up as an alias of `domain1.com`. As such Bill, Ben and Joe have bill@domain2.com, ben@domain2.com and joe@domain2.com.

I want to add some email aliases for both domains, such as joe.bloggs@domain1.com and joe.bloggs@domain2.com.  However, when I add an alias under the 'Profile' section of a user it only adds it to `domain1.com`, which is the actual domain, rather than the alias domain too.

So my question: How can I add an alias for an aliased domain, as well as the normal domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a domain as an alias, rather than a secondary domain, you cannot edit anything before the @ sign. More information about this can be seen [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/182079) on the Google Support site. An alias is just added automatically for everyone for the primary account. This is mostly used for setting up systems like dual delivery (among other things).

If you'd like to specifically add different @domain2.com addresses, you'll need to remove it as an alias and add it back as a secondary domain.

Hope this helps!